# The option android.useNewApkCreator is deprecated

Tags: android, gradle

I got the following error after upgrading the android gradle plugin version to 8.0, how should I fix this problem.

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2

gradle-8.0-bin.zip
```

```
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: The option 'android.useNewApkCreator' is deprecated.
     The current default is 'true'.
     It was removed in version 8.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
```

I did not configure this property `android.useNewApkCreator` in the project.

Adding it now does not work, no matter setting `android.useNewApkCreator=true` or `android.useNewApkCreator=false`

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Android Gradle plugin version 8.0, the new APK creator is always enabled by default, and the `android.useNewApkCreator` option is no longer needed. Therefore, adding or configuring this property will not have any effect.

To fix the issue, you should remove the `android.useNewApkCreator` configuration from your project. Open your project's `build.gradle` file (the one in the project root directory) and search for any occurrences of `android.useNewApkCreator`. Remove the line or lines where this property is set.

After removing the `android.useNewApkCreator` configuration, sync your project with the Gradle files to ensure the changes take effect.

Comment: This error occurred before I configured this property. I added it after this error occurred, and now removing it doesn't work.